# how to center matrix in latex presentation

Tags: latex

```
\centering

\[
\begin{matrix}
  \hline P& \beta^{1p} &\beta^{2p} & \beta^{3p} & \beta^{4p} &E(c^{p}) &\sigma(\delta c^{p}) &E(r^{p}-r^{f}) & \sigma( r^{p}-r^{f}) \\
  \hline 1& 1.4360 & 0.0018& -0.0123 &-0.0195 &0.0292 & 0.0048 &0.0013 &0.0809 \\
   5& 1.1428 & 0.0007 &-0.0098 &-0.0091 & 0.0113 &0.0018 &0.0041 &0.0618 \\
  10& 1.0108 & 0.0005 & -0.0083 & -0.0073 & 0.0086 &0.0013 &0.0042 &0.0544 \\
  15& 0.9065 &0.0004 &-0.0080 &-0.0061 & 0.0068 & 0.0010 &0.0050 &0.0493 \\
  20&0.7602 &0.0003 &-0.0065 & -0.0045 & 0.0050 &0.0008 & 0.0060 & 0.0417\\
  25& 0.7192 & 0.0000 &-0.0061 & -0.0010 & 0.0020 & 0.0003 & 0.0068 &0.0417 
\end{matrix}
\]
```

This is my code and I want this matrix to be more in center.

Comment: any idea will be really helpful. thanks in advance:)

Comment: What presentation format are you using, [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)? Using `\[`...`\]` as you do should suffice for centering content. Regardless, can you please include a minimal example that replicates your behaviour rather than only code snippets? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi @Werner thanks a lot for your reply. In the end it works so I do not know how but it seems that something I was doing wrong, and please accept my apologies for not replying earlier. Again thanks a lot :)